# a problem with cl.exe and ml.exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, cl.exe

I used cl command to compile a cpp file:

```
cl test.cpp  //the generated  test.exe can work well
```

then I used another way:

```
cl /Fa /c test.cpp   //generate a test.asm assembly file
ml test.asm   // there failed!!!
```

why? How to solve it?

source code:

```
//:test.cpp 

 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main()
  {
    cout<<"hello\n";
  }
```

wrong information:

> Assembling:   test.asm 
>   test.asm(1669)   :   fatal   error   A1010:   unmatched   block   nesting
>
> :   ??$?6U?$char_trait 
>   s@D@std@@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@PBD@Z

---

today I write another code in c

```
//test.cpp
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  printf("hello");
}
```

then I compile the code

```
cl /Fa /c test.cpp
ml test.asm //ok!
```

It may be the difference in C and C++. This confuses me a few days. :(

how to solve it?  please help me.

Comment: the code you posted compile fine. maybe it's a problem with your compiler? which compiler are you using? how?

Comment: I use Visual studio 2010

Comment: I repro.  The _TEXT ENDS above the ENDP is misplaced, it needs to be below it.  This happens more than once, it is getting tripped up by the exception handlers you get when you use /EHs (required).  You can report to bug at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: I modified the asm file,put the ENDP below the _TEXT ENDS.but it's the same error.

Comment: I turn off the C++ exception option,and retry. the same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler produces an invalid assembly listing when exception handling code is produced.  There's a bug open on Microsoft Connect: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/556051/cl-facs-generates-bad-masm-for-c-exception-handlers

In a response to the bug, there's a half-hearted "we will consider fixing this" along with a disclaimer that "listing files generated by the C/C++ compiler are for informational purposes".

It looks like you might be able to have a "scriptable" fix for this particular problem:

- cut the `ENDP` statement that follows a `text$x ENDS` statement,
- paste it just before the previous `_TEXT    ENDS` statement

At least that looks to be the pattern in the asm file generated by your simple program - I don't know if that pattern would hold generally.

Unfortunately, after applying this fix, several new problems crop up with instructions using `fs` overrides and a couple undefined symbols.  Who knows what else you'd run into once you tried this with a more complex program?

Comment: Thank you very much.I fix the file as you said.solve the unmatched problem.then I fix `fs` overrides by added `assume fs:nothing` at the head of the asm file.but the second prolbem aboout undefined symbols,I can't solve it yet.

Comment: In 2010 it's [less](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4aad9e70-6bb8-4622-a5d9-a3b07b51fc7f) than "half-hearted": *Before the work was undertaken to target x64 with the Microsoft C/C++ compiler we made the call to no longer support assembling C/C++ generated listing files. In other words, the listing files are for informational purposes only. Even though not supported, listing files from the x86 targeting compiler will potentially be able to be assembled. But with the x64 targeting compiler there will be a number of things that will prevent assembling listing files*