# CL.EXE - Compiling the output assembly

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm getting the assembly output from CL.EXE via /Fa, however, after making some changes with it, how can I re-compile it? Does CL support this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CL.EXE doesn't, but ML.exe does.
Also you can have problems with exceptions, look at the:
[a problem with cl.exe and ml.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488056/a-problem-with-cl-exe-and-ml-exe)

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you know why ml.exe is not in the 2003 C++ toolkit? Apparently ml.exe in VS 2005 does not recognize sar, shl instructions